# Как подключить разные версии jQuery на страницу?

Tags: jquery

Причём желательно не вариант с jQuery.noConflict(true), т.к. подключать в последствии нужно другие страницы со скриптами, а не писать скрипты прямо на этой странице, т.е.

```
<script src='jquery-10'></script>
<script src='jquery-4'></script>

<script src='jquery-plagin-1'></script> //тут нужно чтобы работал jquery-10

<script src='jquery-plagin-2'></script> //a тут нужно чтобы работал jquery-4
<script>                              // + у него есть ещё скрипт на странице
$.('div').jquery-plagin-2();
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915263/include-two-versions-of-jquery-on-a-page-without-affecting-old-plugins

Answer (score 4):

```
// подключаем последнюю версию jQuery
// подключаем jQuery 1.6
var $jq16 = jQuery.noConflict(true);  // сохраняем ссылку
// подключаем jQuery 1.4
var $jq14 = jQuery.noConflict(true);  // сохраняем ссылку

;(function($) {
  // старый плагин, который использует jQuery 1.4
}($jq14));

;(function($) {
  // чуть новее, использует jQuery 1.6
}($jq16));

;(function($) {
  // используем последнюю версию jQuery
}(jQuery));
```

Чем [этот](http://toster.ru/q/29529) вариант не устраивает?

Comment: Так, я так понимаю, что в функциях надо писать код. Как туда можно вставить путь до файла?

Comment: $.getScript - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/