# Разные версии jquery на одной странице

Tags: jquery

В общем, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Форма отправки email "contactable" работает с jquery 1.7.

А калькулятор на jquery 1.11.

На одном jquery оба плагина не работают. :(

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы подгружались обе версии и не конфликтовали между собой?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, поможет ответ в этом вопросе: [Как подключить разные версии jQuery на страницу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/282711/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83)